# Is it possible to make a JDBC connection through SSIS?

Tags: jdbc, ssis

I've never used a JDBC connection before, and am familiar with only ODBC connections. We have a vendor who will only support JDBC. They consider ODBC 'Open Source', and therefore do not support connections to their DB through an ODBC connection. Does anyone know if it is possible to create an SSIS connection via JDBC? I am not getting any hits on this from my initial research online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, SSIS does not have the java interface necessary to do this.  You would have to use an ADO.Net or OLEDB driver, or the OLEDB provider for ODBC to connect to a database.

You could write a java program that extracted the data to a file, and then read the data from that file.  You can execute a process from SSIS, which could be used to run the Java program.